# Authentication error code 2101

Tags: authentication, 19.10

I am trying to launch the cyberghost vpn app. After giving the correct command and password, I get the following message:

> Authentication error! The error code returned is 2101.
>   Wrong login credentials.

The password works for logging in and has always worked in the past for cyberghost but for some reason it is suddenly not accepting it. Can someone please help?

Answer (score -1):

You still have to run setup and configure a new device:

```
$ sudo cyberghostvpn --setup
```

It will create the configuration files in you home folder: `~/.cyberghost`.